# Good Outdoor GunTails libraries for Convolution use

Tags: sound-design, sound-libraries, convolution, impulse-response

I'm the Happy owner of the Guntales library from the Recordist and I had some experiment using these multi-miked recordings as impulse responses for multiple reverbs in parallel. This library focus on the very long Gunshot tails echoing in the silent mountains of Idaho.
 To sum up the process, i fed multiple convolution reverbs (TL space in my case), with these multitrack recordings (close, med, far) and tweaking the aux returns i can "simulate" echoes in the mountain to any sound.It's interesting, so I was wondering about good sounding Gun libraries, multi-miked in interesting spaces, to explore the potential of this.

I put a quick test with  train horns and animals on soundcloud (and a  more detailed explanation of the process) :

https://soundcloud.com/yohannbernard/guntales-sound-library-as-impulse-responses